# QDialog with taksbar icon but parent

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I searched a lot but only found answers for getting rid of the icon. Now what do I want:

1. My Application should open a dialog that behaves as if I do not provide a parent. I.e. it should have a separate taskbar icon, it should not be modal or stay on top of my main window. It should actually behave like windows from other applications.
2. The Dialog should close if my application window is closed.

Not that 2 cannot be achieved by connecting to the main window destroyed signal, since the main window will only be closed, destroyed only if I also close the dialog and hence the application. What I could use is a handmade "close" signal but I need to be able to use any widget as the parent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested how to do that;
use 
`dialog->setAttribute( Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false )`
for the dialog a do not set a parent.

Qt will quit the application if the last window with this attribute set to true is closed. The attribute is enabled by default for window types. Now closing the main window will close the application and hence also close the dialog.